# How does this differential equation solve to give this?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

[image]

Hello I would like to see how this differential equation solves to give the result on the picture.

$c$ is a constant and I believe $\frac{dm}{dt}=-k$ Obviously they are dividing by $m$ and then integrating w.r.t. $t$ yet I can't get the result out myself. Any help.

Here is the pdf by the way it is an MIT document on the rocket equation for reference: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec14.pdf

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\ m\frac{dv}{dt}=-mg-c\frac{dm}{dt}$$
Multiply both members by $\ dt $ and divide by $\ m$:
$$\ dv=-gdt-c\frac{dm}{m}$$
Now integrate to get the result
$$\ \int_{v_0}^v dv=-g\int_0^t dt-c\int_{m_0}^m \frac{dm}{m}$$
$$\ v-v_0=-g(t-0)-c\ln(\frac{m}{m_0})$$
$$\ v=v_0-gt-c\ln(\frac{m}{m_0})$$
Where I supposed that $\ t_0=0$